# Responsive grid of md-cards with different height via angular material

Tags: css, gridview, layout, angular-material

Here is my md-card's loop (except the first `div`):

```
<div layout="column" layout-gt-sm="row" layout-wrap="">
    <div flex="25" flex-gt-sm="50">
        <md-card>
            <md-card-header>
                <md-card-avatar><img src="#" />
                </md-card-avatar>
                <md-card-header-text>
                    <span class="md-title">Angular</span>
                    <span class="md-subhead">Material</span>
                </md-card-header-text>
            </md-card-header>
            <img ng-src="{{imagePath}}" alt="Washed Out" class="md-card-image" />
            <md-card-title>
                <md-card-title-text>
                    <span class="md-headline">Text</span>
                </md-card-title-text>
            </md-card-title>
            <md-card-content>
                <p>
                    Content
                </p>
            </md-card-content>
            <md-button>Button</md-button>
        </md-card>
    </div>
    <!-- another card -->
</div>
```

This works fine, here is the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l35c1.png).
But what if i don't want to display cards strictly on the lines? Is there any way to get something like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egYks.jpg)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That kind of layout will require you to use some javascript to add to the view logic. Since each of your cards are using rows, it would not be currently possible to do that styling.
I would check out http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: I'll check this one, thanks for idea. But if it's possible, I'd like to use angular material way, may be without ' layout="row" ' properties and things like